# Phabricator: Git repository not found

Tags: git, phabricator

I have followed the [Diffusion Hosting](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/diffusion_hosting/) guide to set up Phabricator as my git repository host. However, I have not been able to clone the repo that I created.

Here is the output from Git Bash shell:

```
$ GIT_CURLVERBOSE=1 git clone http://10.20.10.71/source/tdq.git
Cloning into 'tdq'...
fatal: repository 'http://10.20.10.71/source/tdq.git/' not found
```

After executing the command, a popup is displayed asking for my credentials. I enter my Phabricator username and the VCS Password that I set.

Same from PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\kyle\Workspace> set GIT_TRACE=true
PS C:\Users\kyle\Workspace> set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=true
PS C:\Users\kyle\Workspace> git clone http://10.20.10.71/source/tdq.git
Cloning into 'tdq'...
fatal: repository 'http://10.20.10.71/source/tdq.git/' not found
```

And here is the URI setup from Phabricator. The disabled one was when I had `diffusion.allow-http-auth` disabled to attempt anonymous HTTP.

[image: Phabricator URIs]

What am I missing or forgetting to do? What else can I do to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I have a similar problem.